# React Click Event Handling Best Practices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, events, onclick

While learning React I've seen people handle events differently.What are the best practices for handling click events?

Is this way good? Adding the event to the class object to be called with this?

```
import React from "react";

class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    handleClick = handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick(){
    //Do some stuff
  }

  render(){

    return(
      <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Foo
      </div>)
  }
}

export default Foo;
```

Or This Way? To have the function declared in the render "section"

```
import React from "react";

class Bar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render(){
    const handleClick = () => {
      //Do some stuff
    }

    return(
      <div onClick={handleClick}>
        Bar
      </div>)
  }
}

export default Bar;
```

Is there a better way?
Which is the best coding pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen the second way you mention, and would not recommend doing that, as it will create a new function for each render.

The way I do it is like this:

```js
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    //Do some stuff
  }

  render(){

    return(
      <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Foo
      </div>)
  }
}

export default Foo;
```

This way you don't need the bind in the constructor, but the function is still only created once.

Comment: **Lots** of code creates new functions on every render. Ever used `<ul>{someArray.map(entry => (<li>entry.text</li>))}</ul>`? :-) The real problem with the second way is testability.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation [react](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) use:

```
...
    handleClick = handleClick.bind(this)
...
```

But I think, it's better using the following too:
import React from "react";

```
class Bar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    //Do some stuff
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Bar
      </div>)
  }
}

export default Bar;
```

With the second method, you don't care about using `.bind()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first way, using a prototype function you bind in the constructor, is good other than that you're missing `this`:

```
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
```

Your second way creates a new function on every render, inside `render`. That makes it difficult to mock `handleClick` for testing purposes.

A third way you'll often see involves creating an arrow function at construction time, either in the constructor:

```
this.handleClick = event => {
    // ...
};
```

or using a property declaration:

```
class Bar extends React.Component {
    handleClick = event => {
        // ...
    };
}
```

Those both have the same mocking/testability problem.

Other than that, they're fine.